# Pandas Dataframe column addition loop problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I've created a program which creates 100 variants from an original sequence. The main goal of this program is to create 100 variants of a DNA sequence which contains 100 nucleotide. To create variants, we have a original sequence(which has a clone for further modification). and a random number of mutation(between 1-5) are perpetuated over the original sequence. For example if the original strand is 1,2,3,4 the variant can be 1,3,3,4 or 1,4,2,3 ; you get the point. I've also added a if-elif structure which disable the mutated nucleotide to be the same as the original one. I assume you have a little basic knowledge on DNA so I won't over-explain. But i'll gladly answer questions if there are any.

I want to make 100 variants of this and put each variant sequence to a seperate column of a pandas dataframe. What my issue is that, the program creates one variant and the other 99 variants are the same as that one. I couldn't figure out why. If you can advice some modifications on the code to avoid repetiton I would appreciate it.
Down below, there is the code and the result of the code.

The code:

```
import pandas
import random
import pandas as pd


someshit = [4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
        4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 
        4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3,
        3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4]  
r = 0
nucs = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = []
list3 = []
i = 0
j = 0
n = len(someshit)   #LENGTH OF THE SEQUENCE
 #RANDOM MUTATION COUNT

result = None
df = pd.DataFrame({ 0 : someshit })   
    
shitass = someshit #shitass = someshit clone
onehundo = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
            38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
            73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99]
hundred = onehundo #hundred  = onehundo clone
while i < 99:
    x = random.randint(1,5) #RANDOM MUTATION COUNT
    while j < x:
        y = random.choice(hundred)
    
        if shitass[y] == 4:
            nucs.remove(4)
            z = random.choice(nucs)  #z = the new mutated nucleotide
            shitass[y] = z

        elif shitass[y] == 3:
            nucs.remove(3)
            z = random.choice(nucs)  #z = the new mutated nucleotide
            shitass[y] = z

        elif shitass[y] == 2:
            nucs.remove(2)
            z = random.choice(nucs)  #z = the new mutated nucleotide
            shitass[y] = z

        elif shitass[y] == 1:
            nucs.remove(1)
            z = random.choice(nucs)  #z = the new mutated nucleotide
            shitass[y] = z

        nucs = [1,2,3,4] #re-establishes the nucs after every mutation.

        list2.append(y)
        list3.append(z)
        hundred.remove(y)
        #------------------------------------#------------------------------------#------------------------------------
        j = j+1
        
    for r in range(100):
        r = r+1
        result = shitass
        df[r] = result
        hundred = onehundo #re-establishment of the clone
        shitass = someshit #re-establishment of the clone
        r = r+1
        
    i = i+1

    

    
    
print(x)
print(y)
print(list2)
print(list3)
print(shitass)
print(df)
```

The code is really messy, so sorry in advance.
And this was the result I got:

```
2
62
[31, 82, 60, 3, 62]
[4, 3, 1, 1, 1]
[4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4]
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    ...  91   92   93   94   \
0     4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4  ...    4    4    4    4   
1     4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4  ...    4    4    4    4   
2     2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2  ...    2    2    2    2   
3     4    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1  ...    1    1    1    1   
4     4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4  ...    4    4    4    4   
..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   
95    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2  ...    2    2    2    2   
96    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2  ...    2    2    2    2   
97    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3  ...    3    3    3    3   
98    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2  ...    2    2    2    2   
99    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4  ...    4    4    4    4   

    95   96   97   98   99   100  
0     4    4    4    4    4    4  
1     4    4    4    4    4    4  
2     2    2    2    2    2    2  
3     1    1    1    1    1    1  
4     4    4    4    4    4    4  
..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  
95    2    2    2    2    2    2  
96    2    2    2    2    2    2  
97    3    3    3    3    3    3  
98    2    2    2    2    2    2  
99    4    4    4    4    4    4  

[100 rows x 101 columns]
```

Comment: I'd suggest you rename your variables

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is with the statement `shitass = someshit #shitass = someshit clone`  This statement does not create a copy or a clone as you seem to expect.  The following is an illustration of what I mean.

```
la = [1,2,3,1,4,5,6]
lb = la
```

The:

```
print(f"LA = {la}\nLB= {lb}")
```

Yields:

```
LA = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6]
LB= [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now if you modify the contents of lb by:

```
lb[2] = 9
```

and repeat the previous print statement you will see that both la and lb have the same values, because lb = la simply assigns a second name to the same object in python.  This is shown below:

```
lb[2] = 9
print(f"LA = {la}\nLB= {lb}")
```

Yields:

```
LA = [1, 2, 9, 1, 4, 5, 6]
LB= [1, 2, 9, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

To make lb be a clone of la and support independent changes you should use the copy function as follows:

```
lc = la.copy()
lc[2] = 9
print(f"LA = {la}\nLC= {lc}")
```

Which yields:

```
LA = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6]
LC= [1, 2, 9, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```